# Como evitar repetir comandos através de uma função?

Tags: python, funções

Estou criando um programa para fazer algumas contas matemáticas com alguns comandos e tem 1 linha de código que se repete em todas as condições, com apenas uma pequena alteração em cada uma das condições. Minha dúvida é como criar uma função pra chamá-la em vez de digitar essa linha todas as vezes(sei que não vale à pena criar uma função apenas pra não repetir uma linha quando às vezes até iria escrever mais, mas acho que vou precisar aprender a substituir grandes pedaços de código com funções). Segue o meu código e por último a função que tentei criar pra isso.

```
from script_calc import *


command = input()

if '!' in command:
    a = int(command.strip('!')) # esse comando que eu gostaria de substituir todas as vezes que ele é repetido mudando só o caractere que está dentro do strip.
    print(fact(a))

elif 'root' in command:
    a = int(command.strip('root'))
    print(root(a))

elif '²' in command:
    a = int(command.strip('²'))
    print(square(a))

elif '³' in command:
    a = int(command.strip('³'))
    print(cube(a))
```

As funções que foram chamadas:

```
from math import factorial


def fact(a):
    return factorial(a)


def root(a):
    return a ** (1/2)


def square(a):
    return a ** 2


def cube(a):
    return a ** 3
```

Tentei criar essa função para não repetir o comando que eu disse e deu erro:

```
def same(x):
    a = int(command.strip({}).format(x))
```

E então executá-la assim:

```
elif 'root' in command:
        x = 'root'
        same(x) 
        print(root(a))
```

Qual o erro nessa função?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma boa forma de evitar repetir esses comandos na estrutura `if` `else` que tem é utilizando um dicionário com o respetivo texto a ser encontrado no comando e função a utilizar:

```
commands = [
    {'match':'root', 'func': root },
    {'match':'!',    'func': fact },
    {'match':'²',    'func': square },
    {'match':'³',    'func': cube },
]
```

<sup>Por coerencia com o código que já tem utilizei nomes em inglês</sup>

De seguida basta utilizar um `for` para iterar sobre cada um dos commandos e se algum corresponder ao *match* executa-lo e mostrar o valor:

```
input_command = input()

for command in commands:
    if command["match"] in input_command:
        val = int(input_command.strip(command["match"]))
        print(command["func"](val))
        break
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ejQ7ml)

Neste ultimo laço/ciclo `command["match"]` refere o texto a ser encontrado no comando e `command["func"]` a função a ser executada. Podemos também escreve-lo de forma mais detalhada:

```
input_command = input()

for command in commands:
    # o texto a ser procurado no comando
    match = command["match"] 

    if match in input_command:
        # valor obtido do comando
        val = int(input_command.strip(match)) 

        # obter a função armazenada no comando
        command_func = command["func"] 

        # executa-la passando o valor
        result = command_func(val)

        print(result)
        break
```

Com esta solução adicionar um comando resume-se a adicionar um novo objeto na lista de comandos, deixando o `for` inalterado.

Comment: Poderia me explicar a linha do print? Sei o que essa linha faz,  mas acho que não entendi a sintaxe.

Comment: @LucasSouza `command["func"]` tem uma referencia para uma função, a que vem da lista de comandos, por isso você chama como se chamasse uma função normal com `()` passando o valor que relevante. Vou criar uma versão mais detalhada na resposta.